# Send object with SignalR to server

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, signalr

I'm using signalR 2.0 and trying to send an object to the server (ASPNET WEBAPI 4.5) but the object doesn't get to the server.

This is the code on the client

```
var obj = {
    field1: 'a',
    field2: 'b',
    field3: 'c',
    field4: 'd'
};

serverServerHub.saveFormData(obj);
```

I see the obj object with correct data.

This is the code on the server:

```
    public void SaveFormData(DataDto data)
    {
    }
```

And this is the dto

```
public class DataDto 
    {
        public string Field1 { get; set; }

        public string Field2 { get; set; }

        public string Field3 { get; set; }

        public string Field4 { get; set; }

    }
```

Any idea why???

Comment: Did you try handling the .fail on the invocation to see if it's failing for some reason?

Comment: @dfowler, I'll try it later, but my guess is that the way I'm construction the object is what's wrong and the model serializer of .NET cannot read it, but I don't know how should I send it.

Comment: @dfowler, How/Where exactly are you suggesting to include the .fail in that code? I don't have a .post

Comment: The only way it makes sense to use it, serverServerHub.saveFormData(obj).fail(function(err) { console.log(err.message); }). Read the SignalR docs for more details about hub invocations http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/hubs-api/hubs-api-guide-javascript-client#callserver

Answer (score 0):

Try to declare the properties with same case at both places (on client as well as on server)

**Client:**

```
var obj = {
    field1: 'a',
    field2: 'b',
    field3: 'c',
    field4: 'd'
};
```

**Server:**

```
public class DataDto 
{
    public string field1 { get; set; }

    public string field2 { get; set; }

    public string field3 { get; set; }

    public string field4 { get; set; }

}
```